# Python opencv colour change detection on certain places

Tags: python, opencv, colors, camera

I need to detect the color change in a certain point (or line)  and it must do it live(not on a footage taken before). https://youtu.be/wi_dJrCWb54   here is exactly what i want to do , i commented on the video and searched on the internet but no answer seems to come. Can any of you give an idea on how to do it or if you saw code of sth like this system can you send it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not worth doing it on a color image, so you can convert it to gray-scale using `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` and then apply some kind of background subtraction algorithm like [`BackgroundSubtractorMOG2`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d7b/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractorMOG2.html).

The logic of counting the cars will be up to you. That would be my approach since you need real time. If the results are not good, then you can try other things.

Comment: Doing it in gray-scale is logical since i will use a raspberry pi 3 , thanks for the advise.